# What would be the husband of my daughter-in-law for me?

Tags: single-word-requests, kinship-terms

I've been asking myself this question recently:
If I have a daughter-in-law, what would be her husband to me? Do I have any family-related names with him or not at all?

Comment: Presumably he's your son.

Comment: If you have a daughter-in-law and her spouse is male, he would be your *son*; if female, she would be your *daughter*. You can't really have a daughter-in-law without one of those (hint: they are not sold in stores).

Comment: Who is the daughter-in-law? Is this woman married to your son? That is the most common definition of daughter-in-law.  Is she divorced or widowed from your child and now remarried? Do you mean your child’s spouse’s sister- not usually referred to as daughter-in-law in US and UK; I am not sure about other English speaking countries.

Answer (score 2):

The kinship term you're looking for is *son*.

Comment: @Damila, OP asks, "what would be her **husband** to me?"

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry.  I deleted my comment also because I thought of a few possibilities that the OP needs to clarify.